# How to integrate Facebook login in app

Tags: facebook, windows-phone

I am trying to create an app that requires user to login. There should two options in my app, either they enter new details or use Facebook login. I want users to login using Facebook. Is there any tutorial you can point me to?

Comment: This site is for questions about *using* Windows Phone. Development questions should go on Stack Overflow where more developers will see them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you even tried simply googleing "windows phone facebook login"?

Official FB Resource:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone/

Official MS Resource:
http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login/

To get started quickly you should also take a lookt at the Azure Mobile Services. This can take care of authenticating users through MS Account, Facebook, Twitter etc.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://facebooksdk.net/ for windows phone.

You can also find tutoriel to implement a Facebook login